# How to install GNU C++ Development Tools on Raspberry Pi (using apt-get)

Tags: software-development, c++, packages, gcc

Is there a well-known package I should install for C++ Development Tools?

What do I type at the command-line after `sudo apt-get install`?

Ideally, I want the same tools that were installed with "MinGW" on my Windows computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That may depend on your distro, but if you are using raspbian, the stock gcc includes g++, here's the version info:

```
me@RPi» gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
[...]
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
```

So `apt-get install gcc` should work if it isn't already there.

Most distros will build gcc with C++ support, so this should be true for them too.  The easy way to check is to install gcc then try `g++ -v`.

FYI, GCC is the "Gnu Compiler Collection" used by MinGW; `gcc` is the C compiler, `g++` is C++.

To compile C++ code you'll also need the stdc++ header files (`#includes`) from the "libstdc++ dev package".  There is more than one available for raspbian because there are 4 slightly different versions of libstdc++ available.  The one which appears to be the default against which (presumably) all or most binaries in the distro are built looks to me to be 6-4.6.  Check with:

```
dpkg -l | grep ++
```

That's what is currently installed.  If you don't see any libstdc++ listed, then just pick one from what's available (`apt-cache search libstdc++`).  You can have them all installed at the same time, although the system will tend to use only one (there is a symlink based on major version in /lib to *one* of the .so's).  So:

```
apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-dev
```

That *should* (I think) include the base library as a prereq, in which case that and gcc and its prereqs should cover everything.  If it doesn't, just install `libstdc++6-4.6`.  Library packages in most linux distros come in two parts, the runtime, and the headers in a separate `-dev` package for compiling using the API.

Comment: Why not apt-get install build-essential?

Comment: Sure; I'm presuming that's a metapackage and I've never bothered with them but I sure they are handy.  Getting a basic C/C++ environment doesn't require much beyond what will be prereqs for gcc anyway.  The stdc++ dev headers -- I'll add a note.

Answer (score 13):

To install development tools on raspbian :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Which does indeed include `g++`.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. Someone who does not know how to install a compiler probably does not know how to install the other other common developer tools. They just want to run `pip install <package>` (or whatever those Python package managers do) and expect things to just work.

Answer (score 0):

best app for C++ can be found by either searching Code Blocks of going on apps and looking down till you see it and its actually quite near the top. I used this app on my PC before i discovered it on my raspberry pi and has syntax highlighting and everything.

Comment: Hi Luke.  Note that Code::Blocks is an IDE and not a compiler.  It is compatible with gcc (which is the native linux compiler) and the windows visual C++ compiler.